# ReSharper or VS - how can I auto generate a default implementation of a new abstract member in all sub-classes?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, resharper

Suppose the following abstract class:

```
public abstract class Human
{
    public abstract string GetName();
}
```

If I have ten implementations of `Human`, and then add a new member:

```
public abstract class Human
{
    public abstract string GetName();
    public abstract string GetDescription();
}
```

How can I create a default implementation of `GetDescription()` in all my sub-classes? Is this possible?

Comment: I don't have an abstract class in front of me currently, but on Interfaces I get a quick action "Implement in derived classes".

Comment: You know what, for some reason that just wasn't appearing when I hit `Alt-Enter` on my abstract members, and now it is. Or I just didn't see this. But thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I don't know why I wasn't seeing this but simply put the cursor over the member and:

`Alt-Enter` > `Implement in derived classes`

Either I am going blind, or I'm getting old or both because I've been using that for ages...

Thanks, @Lennart